# Visibility based on value of multiple checkboxes

Tags: forms, checkbox, orbeon

Still finding my feet with Orbeon. Hopefully someone can help me with the following. I have a form on which a *checkboxes input* has five options. There is a *text input field* corresponding to each checkbox. You select checkbox two and text input B shows. Select checkbox Four and text input D shows. That's easy, so on text input D the visibility is set as:

```
$checkboxes_input = 'Four'
```

However, if I select checkbox two and checkbox four then none of the text inputs show. So how do I set the visibility on the text input so it shows based on the two conditions, for instance:

```
$checkboxes_input = 'Four' or 
($checkboxes_input = 'Two' and $checkboxes_input = 'Four')
```

> **Note:** Worth saying if I were doing this with JavaScript this would be easy. But I want to do this in the form builder. I see that a previous developer working on this form created a separate checkbox control
>   with a single checkbox for each option required to get around the issue I'm having. Surely that's not required?!

Many thanks :)

### Update

It seems that the following is working:

```
$checkboxes_input = 'Four' or 
$checkboxes_input = 'Four Two' or 
$checkboxes_input = 'Two Four'
```

The need for *Four Two* and *Two Four* is to cover the order in which items are selected.

This is not very satisfactory though as the conditions start getting silly if you have to account for the order options are selected in (which is seems you do) for example I need to track three checkboxes so have:

```
$checkboxes_input = 'Four' or
$checkboxes_input = 'Four Two' or
$checkboxes_input = 'Four Five' or
$checkboxes_input = 'Two Four' or
$checkboxes_input = 'Two Five' or
$checkboxes_input = 'Five Four' or
$checkboxes_input = 'Five Two' or
$checkboxes_input = 'Four Two Five' or
$checkboxes_input = 'Four Five Two' or
$checkboxes_input = 'Two Four Five' or
$checkboxes_input = 'Two Five Four' or
$checkboxes_input = 'Five Two Four' or
$checkboxes_input = 'Five Four Two'
```

...eep. So if all the logic that depends on these options is going to start getting this messy maybe it is better to have each checkbox be its own controller after all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a better way:

```
xxf:split($checkboxes_input) = 'Four'
```

This expression splits the space-separated value of the group of checkboxes on whitespace and then check that 'Four' is included in the resulting sequence.

This solution doesn't have the drawback of the `contains()` solution, which will fail if you have an item value contained in another item value. Say:

```
contains('baz foobar', 'foo')
```

returns `true()`.

Comment: Oh thanks, I hadn't thought of partial matches producing false positives. Thankfully not likely with the medical terms used in our forms but I'll use this method :)

Comment: D'oh thought I had :o)

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

```
contains()
```

...so in my case:

```
contains($checkboxes_input, 'Four')
```

...so as long as the checkbox with value of Four is checked then this will be true for the visibility condition.

Comment: Or, better, IMHO: `xxf:split($checkboxes_input) = 'Four'`.

Comment: I hadn't seen your comment as I wrote a separate answer. But yes, that's the better (and correct) way.